# Comparing cells with array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly I am storing all the data that I want into an array, then I'll compare it with a column; if it matches then i will take the offset of the value and place it into another column.

But here at the array, I am experiencing "invalid qualifier" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub database_updator()

Dim dataa As Range, dataCel1 As Range, dataj As Range, datacel2 As Range, datazc As Range, datacel3 As Range, SrchRngaa As Range, cel As Range

Dim data As String, datatext As String, PDS_NAME As String, Database_data As String
Dim n As Integer, xx As Integer, z As Integer
Set dataa = Range("a16:a100")
Set datazc = Range("zc17:zc50")
Set SrchRngaa = Range("a16:a100")
Dim arr(1 To 85) As String
x = 16
For n = 1 To 85      'storing data into array
    arr(n) = Range("yx" & x).Value
    x = x + 1
Next n


' loop thorugh cells in column
For Each dataCel1 In datazc
    For n = 1 To 85
        If arr(n) = dataCel1.Value Then
            datatext = "true"
        Exit For
        End If
    Next n

' check if current value in column has a match in another column
    If datatext = "true" Then
        PDS_NAME = arr(n).Value    ' ERROR OCCURS HERE
    Database_data = dataCel1.Offset(0, 2).Value
            For Each cel In SrchRngaa
                If PDS_NAME = "" Then

                Exit For
                ElseIf cel.Value = PDS_NAME Then

                        cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = Database_data

                Exit For

                End If
            Next cel
    End If




Next dataCel1

End Sub
```

Comment: you do not need the ".Value" in `arr(n).Value`

Comment: There's no `.Value` property of an array. Try just `= arr(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PDS_NAME = arr(n).Value  

this should be changed to:

PDS_NAME = arr(n)
```